# oneOf nested in array

Tags: jsonschema, jsonforms

I am currently testing JSON Forms on my schema (as is, without a UI definition), and I am running into the following problem: I can generate lists of options with `oneOf` (as shown in `this_works` below), but I am not able to do so within an array (`this_does_not_work` in the minimal example below). Instead, the array will simply offer simple text fields that validate against the options listed in `oneOf`.

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve here? Ideally, the UI of `this_works` (a list that users can select from) would appear for each line of the array:

````
{
    "$id": "schema_test",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "description": "Minimal example",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "this_works": {
            "type": "string",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                "const": "a",
                "title": "Option A"
                },
                {
                "const": "b", 
                "title": "Option B"
                }
            ]
        },
        "this_does_not_work": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                    "const": "a",
                    "title": "Option A"
                    },
                    {
                    "const": "b", 
                    "title": "Option B"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: It doesn't look like that sort of construct is supported: https://jsonforms.io/docs/renderer-sets - UI generation is non-standard and only work as defined for the library.

Comment: Looks like you are right, @Relequestual - the team has now added this as a issue: https://github.com/eclipsesource/jsonforms/issues/1692